# accessing both axes with pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I have to access values from current row and previously calculated value using apply. Below is the code snippet. How can I optimize this code to work faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(30, 1)), columns=['ABCD'])

for idx in range(0, len(df)):
    df.ix[idx, 'flag'] = 0
    if 0 == idx:
        continue
    if df.ix[idx, 'ABCD'] >= 66:
        df.ix[idx, 'flag'] = 1
    elif df.ix[idx, 'ABCD'] <= 33:
        df.ix[idx, 'flag'] = 0
    else:
        df.ix[idx, 'flag'] = df.ix[idx-1, 'flag']

print df
```

Here, I have to use the values from 'ABCD'. If the value is > 66, flag should be set to 1 and < 33, flag should be 0. 
For other values, it should repeat previous value of flag.

Please let me know how to optimize this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to vectorize `if/else`; Set flags as 1 when value >= 66, 0 when value <= 33, NaN otherwise and then do a forward fill on the result `flag` column:

```
df['flag0'] = pd.np.where(df.ABCD >= 66, 1,
              pd.np.where(df.ABCD <= 33, 0, pd.np.nan))
​
df['flag0'] = df['flag0'].ffill()

(df.flag == df.flag0).all()
# True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does the job and works pretty fast.